# Implement X-CSRF pattern

Tags: azure-api-management

I would like to Implement X-CSRF pattern as per the documentation below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/policies/get-x-csrf-token-from-sap-gateway

But the above documentation is for SAP Gateway. Is there any documentation where the Gateway is Azure API-Management gateway itself?

Thanks for your answer in advance.

Regards,
Chaitanya

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking to fetch CSRF token from APIM gateway instead of SAP gateway. The sample policy mentioned above implements X-CSRF token for SAP gateway which uses cookie-based authentication, and the flow is described [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2021/06/04/how-does-csrf-token-work-sap-gateway/). Cookie-based authentication are vulnerable to CSRF attacks, and hence need for X-CSRF pattern.

However, Azure AD is token-based authentication which uses JWT (JSON Web Token) and refer [Prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery (XSRF/CSRF) attacks in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for more info. Also, check SO thread ([Difference between CookieAuthentication and WindowsAzureADAuthentication Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55798472/difference-between-cookieauthentication-and-windowsazureadauthentication-options)) for similar discussion.

[image]

So APIM uses JWT token and doesn't support cookie-based authentication and hence you cannot fetch CSRF token from APIM gateway.